# How should you set power management settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I've noticed since switching to Windows 10 Professional (clean install) that the power settings seem to be causing some odd issues.  I've noticed that even though the system is set to never hibernate or sleep, or turn off disks that it seems to lose the network and USB devices.  Is this caused by Advanced Power settings for USB devices and PCIe link state power management, if so what are the recommended settings and their effects?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that each device in Device Manager can also have power management. For example, go to the properties of a network adapter and you might find a Power Management tab

[image]

I have experienced issues where secondary power managers, like the Lenovo Power Manager, will greatly conflict with the configuration of Windows power settings - ensure you have no other power management software installed.

You should alter your power settings based on your needs. Many will suggest not to use Windows hybernate, as it does not always recover.

Comment: Yep, it was the power management in the Device Manager.  Totally agree on Windows hibernate, it's not totally reliable.

Comment: Great, you should click the green check mark to indicate that this was the answer.

Comment: Your picture shows the bug in the Power Management settings! If first is checked then second should be disabled!